# Autodeleting resource forks on FAT disks

Tags: windows, ntfs, macos, fat32

I totally hate to see those .dsstore and resource files on my Windows disks.

Is there a *free* program that will autodelete those files on specified disks on logout/eject?

Comment: .dsstore and resource files aren't in the same category. For some files, deleting the resource fork will result in substantial data loss.

Comment: for me are in the same category: litter. Of course I won't move system files on a windows disk (why I should), so I think it's 100% safe to delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to remove .DS_Store files; it really depends on what your exact needs are for the method you decide to use. To automatically remove them when you login/logout would be quite different from ejecting a disk, since it's a completely different process. You can disallow .DS_store for from being allowed to write to network disks, etc. by opening up Terminal and entering:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

to manually remove already present .DS_Store files you can use:

```
dot_clean /path/folder
```

which merges any such files with the parent file.

Comment: it's possible to run this command at the logout?

Comment: It's possible to run commands (in the form of a shell script) at logout using what Apple calls a LogoutHook, but the exact method varies depending on the exact version of OS X you're running. [Here](http://my.opera.com/mereh/blog/2011/07/30/apple-osx-mute-startup-sound-chime-in-osx-10-7-lion-and-others) is the general method I've used in the past. The [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) pref pane from Blacktree also has an option for specifying a LogoutHook script.

Comment: @scottishwildcat — awesome explanation and tips! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Resource forks don't exist as actual forks anymore. They have been stored as extended attributes since 10.4.

The files that start with ._ are used to store extended attributes, ACLs, and HFS file attributes / Finder flags. They can be deleted with dot_clean or find:

```
dot_clean /Volumes/Volume
find /Volumes/Volume -name ._\* -delete
```

.DS_Store files can be deleted with find:

```
find /Volumes/Volume -name .DS_Store -delete
```

Another option is to use [BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/):

[image]